# Share constants between iOS client code and Parse cloud code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an **iOS** app that uses **Parse** as backend. There, some cloud code is executed.
Both have to share the same constants.
I can share these constants on the client side via obj-c `#import`, and I can share it on the cloud code side via `module.exports` / `require`.
But how can I share it between client code and cloud code? It is simply error prone to define the same constants twice.

Answer (score 3):

Parse offers a config object that can be queried like a class (returning an `NSDictionary` in iOS).  Moreover, it can be configured via the web UI at parse.com.  [See docs here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#config).

Upon startup, your app can retrieve the config and cache it locally.  You may choose to cache it semi-permanently (say, with `NSUserDefaults`) and then use local copy indefinitely.  I usually opt for some fixed expiration period (like weekly, so my constants are not-quite constant).  Start up logic is, if the interval between now and my last config fetch exceeds the week, fetch again and replace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks interestingly. I will look into it.

Comment: If I understand the docs right, the class Config can be read by the client app and by cloud code. It returns a dictionary, e.g. with constants. However, both client and cloud code have to use the same keys, which had to be hard coded in the client and the cloud - at 2 places, which I wanted to avoid. Am I right?

Comment: You are right.  There's no way to avoid including a key in the client.  The key should be considered insecure.  One must use ACLs and class-level controls to protect the data.

Comment: This looks very useful and I hadn't looked into it before. I just looked in my global.json file of the config and noticed that the ***master*** key is stored in there. Are we sure this is accessible and stored locally on the app? I know the applicationId and clientKey are insecure, but that the master key should never, ever be included in an app (at the risk of it being decompiled and discovered)

Comment: Right.  Master key is secret and should not be in the app.  App will be distributed only with the app key and one of the client keys depending on the platform.

Comment: Good to hear. So to clarify, when the docs say `Caching is used by default to ensure that the latest successfully fetched config is always available.`, the cached config ***will not*** include the master key that's stored in the `global.json` file? Similarly, if I decided to store global variables in there, will they be accessible offline once cached? Thanks for the help and clarification!

Comment: Yes.  The global.json is dev environment config (config for parse console app) and remains private.  Config contains only variables that you define on the parse web app, and (a fact which I forget on the original answer) will be cached for you locally after an initial fetch. It is 100% separate from global.json.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now and thank you for the help @danh. I wasn't making the distinction between the global.json file within config directory of cloud code and the *completely separate* config feature provided by Parse. This feature should come in handy in the future.